# WCF DataReader method return a List

Tags: c#, wcf

I have this Datareader method which determines the data retrieved from the database and I am wondering if there is a way to return a list for PhoneNumber, since each Employee has several phones in the database and I want to show that and not a single number. Is this possible?.

```
   protected static new Employee LoadReader(IDataRecord dr)
    {
        Employee e = null;

        if (dr != null)
        {
            e = new Employee
            {
                FullName = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("FullName")) ? "" : dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("FullName")),
                Age = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetInt32("Age")) ? 0 : dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Age")),
                PhoneNumber = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("PhoneNumber")) ? "" : dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("PhoneNumber"))
            };
        }
        return e;
    }
```

Comment: I think based on this approach you may have to make another call with the EmployeeId to retrieve the matching phone numbers. I assume there is a separate table with phone numbers? Beacause there maybe several phone numbers for an employee i would assume you would create a separate table for EmployeePhoneNumbers - Also just curious not sure if NPoco works in WCF applications but a ORM library may help you too - https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/wiki

Comment: @jedgard exactly, there is another tablee with the id and the phonenumber. How would that call be like?. I am a rookie in WCF

Comment: So you would have a property in your Employee object  like List<long> PhoneNumbers {get; set;}, then when you are reading in the LoadReader, you can make another call to the database with a "SELECT PhoneNumber FROM EmployeePhoneNumbers WHERE EmployeeId = {your employee id}. Then in a separate method called like LoadPhoneNumber() you would read all the records from the response and each time you a new one you add it to the employee collection

Comment: Look at this example, so while you read you do a PhoneNumbers.Add(your read record) populate your phone number list of the employee object. An example here on the while read. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jedgard sounds like a good idea invoking another method just for the phonenumbers, but wouldn't I have the same problem trying to get the list of numbers?.

Comment: Not at all, if you look at that link i posted the data would come as an array of records.. you just need to read each record and do PhoneNumbers.Add(your record).

Comment: This link, where it says while(reader.read()) {} you would read the response of your new call, each iteration is a phone number associated to your employee

Comment: @jedgard I will give it a  try, I have a method just like your example which is the one that invokes this method in the dr.read(), I guess I will add the new method inside that same while loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
       protected static new Employee LoadReader(IDataRecord dr)
        {
            Employee e = null;

            if (dr != null)
            {
                e = new Employee
                {
                    FullName = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("FullName")) ? "" : dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("FullName")),
                    Age = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetInt32("Age")) ? 0 : dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Age"))
                };
                   e.PhoneNumber = LoadPhoneNumbers(e);
            }
            return e;
        }

 protected void LoadPhoneNumbers(Employee employee){

     * Do a read to the database passing the employee id
     * You will receive a reader, this has all your phone number records
     * for each record do
     employee.PhoneNumbers.Add(the phone number)

}
```

Comment: @Gonzalo, if you can avoid putting it in the same loop it would be better.. you can just add another call to populate the employee after you load the employee

Comment: I have written it like you said, although I get an error because LoadPhoneNumbers is a void method and it cannot convert it to List

Comment: You need to add this property in the Employee class and then pass the Employee object you populated to this method. If you want post the whole code and i will take a look.